# How to Cross-Compile Raspberry Pi using Eclipse on Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, raspberry-pi, mingw, cross-compiling

Recently, I got a new raspberry pi, and I want to use Eclipse on Windows with MinGW compiler to build c++ codes and run them on the raspberry pi. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need Cross-Compilation. When you create a project you need to Select the Cross GCC Toolchain and you need to set the Cross compile prefix to: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-"

[Tutorial](http://www.gurucoding.com/en/raspberry_pi_eclipse/raspberry_pi_cross_compilation_in_eclipse.php)

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Gonzo Gonzales, I tried to apply the method mentioned above, but they assumed that I already built [Windows cross-compiler for Raspberry Pi] (http://www.gurucoding.com/en/rpi_cross_compiler/index.php), do you know how to download/build that toolchain